# Upgrade Fiber Optics from 100Base-FX to 1000Base-SX

Tags: networking, switch, fiber

We currently have two HP Procurve 2312s connected using two 100-FX-SC transceivers. I am looking to upgrade to new managed Cisco Catalyst switches that use 1000Base-SX transceivers, will the same cabling I have now work or what will I need to upgrade to make it work?

Comment: What kind of cabling is it? Multimode, singlemode, diameters?

Comment: I'm not sure how would I check?

Comment: It should say a number on the cable. For instance 62.5/125 and 50/125 are very common multi-mode fibers. If it's 50/125 it should also say OM1, OM2, or OM3. 2 and 3 will support 1 Gbps (3 supports 10Gbps). Otherwise it might say 8/125 or 10/125 for single-mode fibers.

Comment: it is 62.5/125 other information on the tag was a tripplite part#N304-003 and SC-ST 0.9M

Answer (score 1):

> it is 62.5/125 other information on the tag was a tripplite part#N304-003 and SC-ST 0.9M

That will support Gigabit Ethernet over that distance.  However you need to check that the physical interface on the new switch transceiver matches your current transceiver (which is SC) and I suspect they won't match.

You can use [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_connector) to help identify connectors, if you know the model of the Cisco switch.  It's likely that it is using a [SFP module](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/ps6577/product_data_sheet0900aecd8033f885.html).

Comment: Cisco Catalyst 2960-8TC
and
Cisco Catalyst 3560-12PC

Comment: well the distance from one office to the other is about 400 ft, that is only the wire from the switch to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few things.

1. Distance, by your comment it's 400ft (~130M), this should be ok with any SX transceiver
2. Patch cables, also by your comments I think you'll need to purchase new ones, probably LC-ST. [Here's an example](http://www.lighthousefiber.com/ProductInfo.aspx?productid=FP-D01-LCPSTP-001)
3. Installation cable, the cable used on the main run, if it's 50/125 (OM2) no problem, if it's 62.5/125 (OM1) then it might work, but isn't strictly to spec

Comment: I've seen gig run over *really* long runs of multimode, on the order of almost a kilometer.  What the spec says and what you can do if you need to and don't have the money to pull new fiber are two different things.  considering that 2 sfp modules would cost less than $100 on ebay, it's worth just plugging it in and seeing if it works. (and this was 62.5, not 50 micron cable)